# I installed PHP7 but apache2 directory in /etc is not created. Now what?

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

Commands I did run:

```
sudo apt-get install php php7.0-common php-pear php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm
```

After installing, I can see only these directories under `/etc/php/7.0/` directory:

- cli/
- fpm/
- mods-available/

I had apache already installed and running while installing PHP. Obviously, I would like to use LAMP on my server, but without access to php.ini I am pretty much done

What should I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install a package for that. D'oh!

Running:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

resolved the problem.